# What exactly happens when you 'index' a MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

So I understand that indexes are crucial because they allow you to make queries without having to look at the entire collection, but what exactly is an index? What really happens to the data when you call .createIndex()?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this should help you

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3iWPF5jP-g&feature=youtu.be

HTH.